# Oculus grab interactions not working on imported 3D models from DB - Unity/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculusquest

I am working on an Oculus project with Unity and I bumped in the following problem:
My project requires me to import some 3D models, TriLib is being used for this), with whom I want to interact both via ray interactions and grab interactions (not at the same time).
I create a prefab object that already contains the grabbable component, the rigidbody required, the grab interactable and the collider.

When I import the object placing it inside the prefab, I take its mesh, create a meshcollider and assign it to the collider for the interactions, but when I try to grab the object in the scene nothing happens. While they ray interactions do work.

I've already tried to manually download the model, place it in the assets and load it in the scene through using Resource.Load and the grab interactions work fine in this case, even if the hierarchy and the inspector components/properties look the same.

Anyone has any idea on what else could I be doing wrong?

EDIT: with more testing and a calmer mind, I found out that the interactions that are not working are the Hand Grab Interactions. Still on the other model, the one loaded through the resources, they do. I am even more perplexed but I hope it can help to have a wider and more complete view on the problem.